# How can I use conditionnal data validation to check wether user enters a formula or a value?

Tags: validation, google-sheets, formula

I want to use conditionnal data validation in google spreadsheets for let's say cell `A1` based on a custom formula to check wether a user entered a formula or some random value that should be rejected.

Here is the custom formula for the data validation: `=ISFORMULA($A1)`

Here is the test formula I enter in cell `A1`: `=ROW(D4)`

and here is the other value I enter that should be rejected: `a`

So one is a formula the user should be able to write and the other a value **`a`** that should be rejected.
I get weird behaviours, sometimes the error message pops up, sometimes don't and even when the cell contains a formula I get a text attached to the cell telling me the value doesn't meet data validation's criteria.

Here's the [spreadsheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bt1yA0tOXFU223rdxMpdH-H2uTUZSQouzTuNQSxW5Rk/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Could you post a sample with your formula / data?

Comment: @GrzegorzMogilewski I've just added the spreadhseet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation with JSmith it looks like some bug in GS. If your custom formula is self referencing and is using:

```
=ISFORMULA(A1)
```

to make it work you have to change "On invalid data" to "Show warning" (not "Reject input"). Its weird but works (but you have to live with red triangle).

Other tested formulas seems to work...

Comment: but I've already self referenced a value and it worked fine. I'm adding another data validation on A2 in the spreadsheet

Comment: yes, it is weird - other formulas works as expected (but not ISFORMULA)

Comment: I'll wait if someone has another answer an mark yours as an answer if no other good answers shows up. Best

Comment: Definitely - I am waiting too for better answer!